# C# Regex extract (ip + whitespace + port) in long string

Tags: regex, ip, port

I'm having trouble with a regex in C# to extract **IP + Port** with format `X.X.X.X Port`, in middle of a long string.

Example of a string:

> "C:/programs/CamClient/ver/0.0.1.202/client.exe" "12345"
>   "RemoteClient.exe" "/path" "118.118.118.118 5978
>   AInRy+Nj9CVVaE6iCN1hSQ== 106937037""-UseNewX3DFramebuffers=0"
>   "-ClientPort=55000" "-AuthToken=hC-dlUy2rLe7CUQDtk2LOQ"

**I need extract "118.118.118.118 5978" as a new String
IP are always external, and port are always between 5000-5999, to be more accurate**

My actual regex seens not working, and I've already tried to solve and ended up by getting lost in middle of Regex world.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}[\s]\d{1,4}$");

        String testString = "asdaasd32 as333 /remote 'ID93494' 118.118.118.118 5978 AInRy+Nj9CVVaE6iCN1hSQ=='106937037'";

        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(testString);
        foreach (MatchCollection match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
        }
```

if anyone has a idea about what im doing wrong, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the starting ^ and ending $ from your regex:

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3} +\d{4}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ku0JfU/1)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this regex.

```
(?:(?:2[0-5][0-5]|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.){3}(?:2[0-5][0-5]|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\s(5\d{3})
```

Comment: this best answer , because this match IP address valid (0-255)